# VHDL how to have multiple conditions in if statement

Tags: if-statement, vhdl

I'm trying to do an if statement that checks if bet_target is one of many numbers, the code looks something like this:

```
bet_target : in unsigned(5 downto 0);

if (bet_target = 1 or bet_target = 2 or bet_target = 3) then
            --do stuff  
end if;
```

The bet target is any number from 0 to 36 in binary from 6 switches. Is there a more compressed way for writing a statement as such?

Thanks

Comment: You may find this answer useful: [How can I build if sentence with compare to various values?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34501004/2352082)

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the IEEE package numeric_std you can use comparisons as in

```
if bet_target >= 0 and bet_target <= 36 then
    ...
```

Note that unsigned expects natural range integer values as operands for relational operators.

(Also note the superfluous parentheses have not been included - they are permitted).

These relational operators return boolean values and the and in the middle would be a boolean logical operator.

The place to look for how and why is in the IEEE numeric_std package declarations and IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.2 Operators.

And realizing that an unsigned is going to have a binary equivalent of a natural number you could express this with a single condition:

```
if bet_target <= 36 then
    -- do something

end if;
```